# NAT traversal using free STUN and TURN servers in C#

Tags: c#, p2p, stun, nat-traversal, turn

This is my previous post:

[NAT Traversal using only free STUN and TURN servers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456570/nat-traversal-using-only-free-stun-and-turn-servers-in-c-sharp)

I am making an online application that communicates with each other peer-to-peer. Most users are expected to be in their private network behind a NAT, and I need to traverse it. I can't afford an external server, so the only things that I can depend on is free servers like [Numb](http://numb.viagenie.ca/) (which means I cannot provide my own implementation or extension of it.)

However, after some research, I couldn't figure out how to use such servers. I didn't find a library that could be used with C# either.

How should I use such servers to establish a connection over networks? Is there a library to simplify those stuff? (I'm a high-school student and I can only use a free one.) It would be better if it also implemented ICE protocol.

Some people suggested I use UPnP, and that indeed did work well for me, but some of the users did not like to turn on the UPnP on their routers. That's why I'm asking it here again.

Comment: A C# STUN client (that includes source) is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18492/STUN-Client

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can use  OfficeSIP TURN Server which is written in C#

http://sourceforge.net/projects/turnservernet/